# WPF, XAML Datagrid - Context Menu only in last row enabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, contextmenu

I must make a Context Menu but it should only enabled on last row. In all other rows it should be disabled. I have 1 or x rows.

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="change_entry" Header="change entry"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: How do you populate your datagrid? I think the solution will depend on it. Some more code will help to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind `ContextMenu.IsEnabled` property to `DataGrid.SelectedIndex` and `DataGrid.Items.Count` properties with `IMultiValueConverter`. It will update if any of this values changed. Here is XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="DataGridMenuTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridMenuTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SelectedRowToBoolConverter x:Key="SelectedRowToBoolConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="MainGrid">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu.IsEnabled>
                                <MultiBinding  Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource SelectedRowToBoolConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="SelectedIndex"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="Items.Count"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </ContextMenu.IsEnabled>

                            <MenuItem Name="change_entry" Header="change entry"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>           
    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is converter code behind:

```
public class SelectedRowToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return false;

            int selectedIndex = (int)values[0];
            int rowsCount = (int)values[1];

            return (selectedIndex == rowsCount - 1);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice solution but...Can it fails if you select a row and right click on the column header?? I think it will show the context menu to

Comment: @Kirenenko Then you can set DataGridRow as parent of ContextMenu instead of DataGrid.

Comment: @Kirenenko Answer updated. I didnt test the code but it should work.